# Если шифровать пароль с помощью password_hash то можно не боятся за иньекции?

Tags: php

Я правильно понимаю запись такого вида в бд $2y$10$xHoandcfNIz2d1Tp0xQ79elFzWSPqG5WHOhO3KnUI3a.L3Hzucu46 
Не может же причинить вреда? что бы кто не написал

Comment: Если вы об SQL-инъекциях, то нужно организовывать работу с базой так, чтобы они были в принципе невозможны вообще никак — независимо от того, что там в password_hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, перед записью в базу, следует использовать подготовленные запросы, тогда можно не париться за содержимое.
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Ответ на ваш вопрос - да, хеш от пароля можно писать в базу спокойно. Однако, вам нужно изначально понять какую запись вы собираетесь заапдейтить и создать, т.е. кроме пароля, нужно санитизировать и остальные поля, такие как логин?id? что-то еще. Поэтому настоятельно советую ознакомиться со статьей по ссылке.